# Jquery not working on Mobile Devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I just managed to get my header to hide after scrolling using the following script:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(window).scroll(function () { 
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
      $('#topContainer').hide();
    } else {
      $('#topContainer').show();
    }
  });
});
```

I need this to work more in Mobile because ...well have a look for yourself on mobile: www.lendenapp.com

Keep in mind i am currenty improving the responsive side so disregard that part XD.

Thanks guys.
Alex

Comment: Sorry, I read your question, checked the website on my mobile, and couldn't understand your definition of "not working"

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify my objective. I am trying to hide the header which is fixed behind my content when you scroll. I am wanting to do this on mobile because when you try scrolling it's not smooth.